# Should I synchronize with self or with the method argument?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronized

In a method like this, which do synchronize (i.e. `self` or `thing`)?

```
- (BOOL)deleteThing:(MSThing *)thing error:(NSError **)error
{
    @synchronized(self)  {
        if (!thing) {
            return YES;
        }

        NSString *fileName = [[self thingDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:thing.cacheInstanceName];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName]) {
        //...
```

=== OR ===

```
- (BOOL)deleteThing:(MSThing *)thing error:(NSError **)error
{
    @synchronized(thing)  {
        if (!thing) {
            return YES;
        }

        NSString *fileName = [[self thingDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:thing.cacheInstanceName];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName]) {
        //...
```

Comment: multiple threads are accessing self?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case,

```
@synchronized(self)  { ... }
```

the code will not be executed simultaneously by two threads calling the method on the same
*instance* (`self`). This is probably what you want if the code accesses or modifies the instance
in a thread-unsafe way.

In the second case,

```
@synchronized(thing)  { ... }
```

the code will not be executed simultaneously by two threads calling the method with
the same *argument* (`thing`).

Comment: On the (thing) version does this also block code on different method with the same object?   destroy(thing) alter(thing)

Comment: Thanks very much. All the documentation I have been reading yet the answer was never written better than you have done it here.