# What is the parameter that @synchronized() takes

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, mutex, synchronized

I know what @synchronized() does, but... 
sometimes we have:

1- `@synchronized(self)` 
2- `@synchronized([MyClass class])` 
3- `@synchrinized(myObj)`

What is the **difference**, and what is the parameter I should pass to this block ?

Comment: You should pass @synchronized(self)

Comment: Similar question: [Should I synchronize with self or with the method argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461968/should-i-synchronize-with-self-or-with-the-method-argument).

Comment: @Natarajan, why ? always ?

Comment: `@synchronize()` is same `NSLock` i guess. Used to make it as thread safe

Comment: you should be sure not guess :) I am asking what is the parameter that should be passed @Anil

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html):

> The object passed to the `@synchronized` directive is a unique
>   identifier used to distinguish the protected block. If you execute the
>   preceding method in two different threads, passing a different object
>   for the `anObj` parameter on each thread, each would take its lock and
>   continue processing without being blocked by the other. If you pass
>   the same object in both cases, however, one of the threads would
>   acquire the lock first and the other would block until the first
>   thread completed the critical section.

So it depends on what you want to protect from being executed simultaneously,
and there are applications for all three cases.

For example, in

```
-(void)addToMyArray1:(id)obj
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self.myArray1 addObject:obj];
    }
}

-(void)addToMyArray2:(id)obj
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self.myArray2 addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

both `@synchronized` blocks cannot be executed simultaneously by two threads calling
the method on the same *instance* (`self`), thus protecting simultaneous access to the
arrays from different threads.

But it also prevents the block from the first method
to be executed simultaneously executed with the block from the second method, because they
use the same lock `self`. Therefore, for more fine-grained locking, you could use
different locks:

```
-(void)addToMyArray1:(id)obj
{
    @synchronized(self.myArray1) {
        [self.myArray1 addObject:obj];
    }
}

-(void)addToMyArray2:(id)obj
{
    @synchronized(self.myArray2) {
        [self.myArray2 addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

Now the simultaneous access to `self.myArray1` and `self.myArray2` from different threads
is still protected, but independently of each other.

A lock on the *class* can be used to protect access to a global variable.
This is just a trivial example for demonstration purposes:

```
static int numberOfInstances = 0;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        @synchronized([self class]) {
            numberOfInstances++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: better to pass the critical section than passing self everytime right ? in this case _obj

Comment: @Basheer_CAD: I do not understand you question. What is _obj ?

Comment: for example I am using a method to change _obj (writing by multiple threads), it's better to use @synchronized(_obj) and then change this object inside {...}. Just in case self is used as a token in other @synchr.. block from another thread ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD: Yes, if you have a single object to protect (as the arrays in my answer) then you can just lock this object (that's actually simpler and I have updated the answer accordingly). - But there might be more complicated cases (e.g. a sequence of statements to protect) that need a dedicated lock.

Comment: If I understood, is the first example protecting array1 and array2 both?

Answer (score -2):

@synchronized should have the same object passed each time. So @synchronized(self) would work best.

Comment: That depends on what you want to protect. There are also use-cases for `@synchronized([MyClass class])` or `@ synchronized(someObj)`.

Comment: @MartinR, yes probably when you have a singleton ?

Comment: If you have a singleton, it wouldn't make a difference since there is only one instance. No, it just depends on the situation. If performing the same code for any other object of the same class would be a problem, you synchronize on the class. Also to remember:  "@synchronized" should be used for the smallest possible amount of time (so do all calculations outside the "@synchronized") and try avoiding nested "@synchronized" statements on different objects to avoid deadlocks.